# installing linux on full disk encrypted machine

Tags: linux, windows, truecrypt, multi-boot, disk-encryption

I have machine with windows 7 installed and full disk encryption using TrueCrypt. I'm wondering if there is a way to install linux next to windows but without reinstaling everything and loosing data?

On normal machines without truecrypt I've done it like that:

1. shrink windows partition
2. create new partition from free space
3. install linux on new partition

But I don't know if it is a good way of doing it with true crypt.

Answer (score 3):

Partition tools cannot change the size of TrueCrypt partitions. You have to unencrypt the partition, then make your partition changes, then re-encrypt the now smaller partition.